# Percentage constraint width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I have a view with a width value of 700. I also place several buttons and an image inside this view. The problem is exactly that I asked them the width and when the device changed to a device with a large screen, these objects did not stretch as needed.

Then I read that you can set the width as a percentage so that the interface is good. My button whose width value was = 32. I made the width equivalent to view and set the factor to 0.32. But the result has not changed, and in appearance the button has become even smaller.

How can I set the percentage width correctly so that the button automatically resizes to fit the size of this view ??

Comment: share your code and design please

Comment: @Sh_Khan Sorry, unfortunately I can’t show the design. But he is very simple. A wide view, on which there is a button with a parameter of width = 32. It is necessary to somehow adjust this as a percentage for a good display on the screen. And I do not use the code for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the multiplier relative to the superview.

So, if you have originally designed your button to be 32-pts wide, and its superview (the view it is embedded in) is 700-pts wide, your button width should be equal to the superview width with a multiplier of `32:700`

Here is an example -- I'm starting with button width of `32` and view width of `300` to make it easier to see the "stretching".

The button width constraint is:

```
Proportional Width to: Superview
Multiplier: 32:300
```

[image]

So, when I change the width of the superview to `400`, `500`, `600`, `700`, you can see that the button stretches while remain proportional:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so mutch. This is what I needed. Now I realized that my mistake was in the multiplier. Thanks again!!